# Prove continuous sup-property.

Tags: real-analysis

It is a question from pugh's real mathematical analysis.
Suppose that $\mathcal E \subset C^0$ is equicontinuous and bounded. (We can consider $C^0$ is the set of continuous functions defined on $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$)

a)Prove that $\sup \{f(x):f\in \mathcal E \}$ is continuous.

b)Show that a) fails without equicontinuity.

c)Show that this continuous sup-property doesn't imply equicontinuity.

d)Example for continuous sup-property holds for each subset $\mathcal F \subset \mathcal E$, but $\mathcal E$ is not equicontinuous.

I think I worked out part b,c,d.

But I am having trouble proving part (a). My attempt is let $g(x)=\sup \{f(x):f\in \mathcal E \}$. Let $x$ be arbitrary in $[a,b]$, need to show $|y-x|<\delta \implies |g(x)-g(y)|<\epsilon$.

By the definition of sup, we have $f_1,f_2 \in \mathcal E$ such that $|g(x)-f_1(x)|$ and $|g(y)-f_2(y)|$ can both be made as small as we need.

Also, $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq|g(x)-f_1(x)|+|f_1(x)-f_1(y)|+|f_1(y)-f_2(y)|+|f_2(y)-g(y)|$

By equicontinuous, the second term can be made arbitrarily small. But I am stuck with the third term.

I feel like I need to apply Afzela-Ascoli Theorem, but have no idea where to start. Maybe define $f_n(x)$ such that $|g(x)-f_n(x)|<\frac{1}{n}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
|x-y|<\delta\implies|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon\quad\forall f\in\mathcal E.
$$
If $|x-y|<\delta$, Then, for any $f\in\mathcal E$
$$
f(x)=f(x)-f(y)+f(y)<f(y)+\epsilon\le g(y)+\epsilon.
$$
Taking the sup in $f$
$$
g(x)\le g(y)+\epsilon.
$$
Similarly, prove
$$
g(y)\le g(x)+\epsilon.
$$